# With Xamarin Forms, how can I set size for displaying an image when ImageSource is memory stream?

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, display

I have a form with a list of view cells.  Some of the cells display an image.  Some do not.  I'm trying to set the ImageSource for the image in OnAppearing.  If I do this, the images, for the cells that have them, will display, but will not be sized properly.  If two consecutive cells have images, the image for the second cell is covering up the first cell's image.  In other cases, a cell's image will display, but following cells are displayed on top of the image from the earlier cell.

Basically, the image is displaying, but height/width properties are not set correctly or at all, which results in display issues with previous and/or subsequent cells.  It also results in an incorrect area that can be tapped on to do something.  Is there a way to fix this?  Here is my code:

```
using Application.ViewModels.ItemViewModels;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Application.Views.ViewCells
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ItemDetailViewCell : ViewCell
    {
        public MessageDetailViewCell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Displays image properly, but height/width is incorrect, resulting in display issues with neighboring cells.
        // Also affects surface area of cell for user tap.
        // imageData is of type byte[]
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            var imageData = ((ItemDetailViewModel)BindingContext).ImageData;
            if (imageData != null && imageData.Length > 0)
            {
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
                image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    var stream = memoryStream;
                    return stream;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                image.Source = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As an alternate approach, I tried using Xaml binding of ImageSource to ImageData, using a converter to create the MemoryStream out of the byte array.  That did not work either.

Comment: you mean set Image size in xaml doesn't work ?could you show a screenshot ?then could find the problem more intuitively.

Comment: That is the ONLY thing that I found to consistently work.  I don't see why I should need to set the image size.  It should be retrieving the size from the image itself.  Is there a way to do that in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: try to set HorizontalOptions ,VerticalOptions and Aspect to the image axml

Comment: One thing I found is that if the image is larger than the display area, depending on height/width ratio, you can end up with extra space that looks like a margin or padding.   I solved my problem by 1) reducing the size of the images of which I really wanted more of a thumbnail type display and 2) setting proper height/width of the image.